# How to filter out a row in a csv file based on one of the column values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i have csv file "file.csv". with columns `policy`, `premium`, and `policytype`. I want to filter out the row after providing unique policy. I am using python 3.8.

CSV file as below:

```
policy premium policytype
101    200.34  lIFE
102    234.34  AUTO
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use `pandas`. It's a very useful module to work with csv files, etc.
I recommend you search information about it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('something.csv', index_col=0)

row_filter = []
value_to_filter = 101

for key, value in df.iterrows(): # Iterate through the rows
    if key == value_to_filter: # Any kind of value in policy
        row_filter.append([key, value])

# What you're looking for is stored in row_filter[]
```